# Custom Command Line in Dart

Tags: dart

I remember seeing an article or example about custom command line in dart, but I can't find the example that I saw.

I want to create an application that looks like a terminal but is actually a full application.

If you know where this custom command line example is, or can provide your own example, that would be greatly appreciated.

Basically, I want to create my own "Powershell" application, but in dart.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for command line apps](https://dart.dev/tutorials/server/cmdline) should give you everything you need to get started.

Comment: I want to be able to add color, change the text on a line (similar to a console download progress bar), and things like that. I remember seeing something about this somewhere, but I can't find it again. 

When I look through the docs you linked, I don't see any info about this unless I just keep missing it

Comment: In short: `print('\u{1B}[36mAAA\u{1B}[41mBBB\u{1B}[0mCCC');` The numbers 36 and 41 here were arbitrarily chosen. They specify the green text colour, and the red background colour. Check the source of (or perhaps use) https://pub.dev/packages/colorize. It's pretty straight forward.